# Dealloc is called but memory not releasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I am trying to find memory leak in my code but don't understand where is the problem.
In my iOS application I use sliding menu navigation pattern. Navigation controllers can be switched using sliding menu. After logging out all controllers should be deallocated and the memory should be freed. But some controllers stay in the memory after logging out in spite of the fact that dealloc is called and reference count in Instruments seems normal.

SettingsViewController

```
#   Category    Event Type  RefCt   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   SettingsViewController  Malloc  1   MyApp   -[SlideViewController didSelectMenuItem:]
1   SettingsViewController  Autorelease     MyApp   -[SlideViewController didSelectMenuItem:]
2   SettingsViewController  Retain  2   UIKit   -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:]
3   SettingsViewController  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
4   SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
5   SettingsViewController  Retain  4   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
6   SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
7   SettingsViewController  Release 3   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform
8   SettingsViewController  Release 2   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform
9   SettingsViewController  Release 1   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform
10  SettingsViewController  Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
11  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
12  SettingsViewController  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
13  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
14  SettingsViewController  Retain  4   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
15  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
16  SettingsViewController  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
17  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
18  SettingsViewController  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
19  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
20  SettingsViewController  Release 5   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
21  SettingsViewController  Release 4   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
22  SettingsViewController  Release 3   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
23  SettingsViewController  Release 2   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
24  SettingsViewController  Release 1   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
25  SettingsViewController  Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
26  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
27  SettingsViewController  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
28  SettingsViewController  Retain  4   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject addMappingFromIdentifier:toObject:forCoder:]
29  SettingsViewController  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
30  SettingsViewController  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
31  SettingsViewController  Retain  7   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
32  SettingsViewController  Retain  8   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
33  SettingsViewController  Retain  9   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
34  SettingsViewController  Retain  10  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
35  SettingsViewController  Retain  11  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
36  SettingsViewController  Retain  12  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
37  SettingsViewController  Retain  13  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
38  SettingsViewController  Retain  14  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
39  SettingsViewController  Retain  15  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
40  SettingsViewController  Retain  16  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
41  SettingsViewController  Retain  17  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
42  SettingsViewController  Retain  18  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
43  SettingsViewController  Retain  19  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
44  SettingsViewController  Retain  20  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
45  SettingsViewController  Retain  21  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
46  SettingsViewController  Retain  22  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
47  SettingsViewController  Release 21  UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
48  SettingsViewController  Release 20  UIKit   +[UIProxyObject removeMappingsForCoder:]
49  SettingsViewController  Release 19  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
50  SettingsViewController  Release 18  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
51  SettingsViewController  Release 17  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
52  SettingsViewController  Release 16  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
53  SettingsViewController  Release 15  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
54  SettingsViewController  Release 14  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
55  SettingsViewController  Release 13  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
56  SettingsViewController  Release 12  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
57  SettingsViewController  Release 11  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
58  SettingsViewController  Release 10  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
59  SettingsViewController  Release 9   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
60  SettingsViewController  Release 8   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
61  SettingsViewController  Release 7   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
62  SettingsViewController  Release 6   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
63  SettingsViewController  Release 5   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
64  SettingsViewController  Release 4   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
65  SettingsViewController  Release 3   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
66  SettingsViewController  Release 2   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
67  SettingsViewController  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
68  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
69  SettingsViewController  Retain  4   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
70  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
71  SettingsViewController  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
72  SettingsViewController  Release 4   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
73  SettingsViewController  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
74  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
75  SettingsViewController  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
76  SettingsViewController  Release 5   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
77  SettingsViewController  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
78  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
79  SettingsViewController  Retain  7   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
80  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
81  SettingsViewController  Retain  8   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
82  SettingsViewController  Release 7   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
83  SettingsViewController  Retain  8   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
84  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
85  SettingsViewController  Retain  9   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
86  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
87  SettingsViewController  Release 8   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
88  SettingsViewController  Release 7   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
89  SettingsViewController  Release 6   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
90  SettingsViewController  Release 5   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
91  SettingsViewController  Release 4   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
92  SettingsViewController  Release 3   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
93  SettingsViewController  Release 2   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
94  SettingsViewController  Release 1   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
//controller is loaded now 
//then logout button will be pressed and the memory should be released
95  SettingsViewController  Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
96  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
97  SettingsViewController  Release 1   UIKit   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
98  SettingsViewController  Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
99  SettingsViewController  Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
100 SettingsViewController  Release 1   UIKit   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
```

This log shows that reference count at the end is 1 and object is not over retained. 
Another controller is released properly. Instruments log for it looks the same but in the end of log there are 2 additional calls:

```
//controller is loaded now 
//then logout button will be pressed and the memory should be released    
75  SummaryViewController   Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
76  SummaryViewController   Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
77  SummaryViewController   Release 1   UIKit   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
78  SummaryViewController   Retain  2   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
79  SummaryViewController   Autorelease     UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
80  SummaryViewController   Release 1   UIKit   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]
81  SummaryViewController   Release 0   UIKit   -[UIViewController dealloc]
82  SummaryViewController   Free    0   UIKit   -[UIViewController dealloc]
```

Debugging shows that dealloc is called for both controllers. And I don't understand why first controller stays in memory but second is deallocated properly.

Allocation of SettingsViewController:

```
self.settingsNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]] autorelease];
[self.navigationControllers addObject:_settingsNavigationController];
```

Allocation of SummaryViewController:

```
self.summaryNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:[[[SummaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]] autorelease];
[self.navigationControllers addObject:_summaryNavigationController];
```

Dealloc of SlidingController:

```
- (void)dealloc
{    
    [self.navigationControllers removeAllObjects];
    self.summaryNavigationController = nil;
    self.settingsNavigationController = nil;
    self.navigationControllers = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance that you figured this out?  I have the same problem!